# How can I remove Opera's system tray icon in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, system-tray, opera

I installed Opera on Lubuntu 13.04, and Opera places an icon *in the system tray*. Really odd and unacceptable behaviour.

Is there a setting in Opera which allows you to remove the system tray icon?

Answer (score 2):

To disable it, edit the Opera launcher to `opera %u -notrayicon`  Or to edit, just navigate to `/usr/share/applications`, Right click on Opera, choose properties, and add the `-notrayicon` to the end of the command.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Type in the URL bar:

   > opera:config
2. Search by:

   > show tray icon
3. and disable it.

---

*Source:* https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/97TsP2MQ1Ebtai_nriKW3M5KvRTtSg_DvVDm2URhcARRFfSpum64boqCSEtiX4UzFkZBlGrGnyE